# Exibir zero em group by SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ireport, join

Tenho uma tabela que chama `Ordem`, nela tem um campo que representa o Status da ordem de serviço (0 a 7), eu preciso plotar um gráfico no Ireport, só que eu queria exibir na legenda o nome do status quando o valor for zero.

O select teria que retornar algo do tipo:

```
Status - Total
0        30
1        2
2        0
3        9
4        0
5        44
6        6
7        0
```

Alguém tem algum exemplo de Query no Sql Server que possa retornar os 8 status ?

Comment: Pode colocar uma modelagem no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Uma simples consulta `select status, count(*) as total from tabela group by status` não funcionou pra você? Veja esse SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b72ea/2

Comment: Então essa consulta @Eduardo Silva eu já realizei, mais eu preciso por exemplo, quando o status 7 não estiver inserido na tabela retorne com a query o status 7 e o valor 0. Unica forma que consegui foi utilizando 8 select com UNION, mas acho que dessa forma a consulta pode ficar lenta quando existir uma quantidade grande de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode "simular" uma tabela com todos os status existentes e então fazer um select sobre esta tabela ligando-a através de um **left join** com a tabela `Ordem`, assim:

```
declare @Status Table (
    Status int)

insert into @Status values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)

select 
    Status.Status,
    count(Ordem.Satus) as Total
from 
    @Status as Status 
    left join Ordem on Status.Status = Ordem.Satus
group by
    Status.Status
order by
    Status.Status
```

No código acima, eu usei o recurso do SQL Server chamado ***table variable***, que permite declarar uma variável como sendo do tipo de uma tabela, então você lida com esta variável como se estivesse lidando com uma tabela normal.

Algumas notas:

- Você precisa dar um *alias* para a *table variable* para poder utilizar seus campos no SELECT. Eu fiz isso assim: *from @Status **as** Status* (repare no uso da palavra chave *as*).
- Eu fiz o select sobre *table variable* ligando-a com **left** join a fim de garantir que todos os status sejam retornados independentemente de haver valor para eles na tabela `Ordem`.

## Outra opção:

Se eu pudesse manipular o resultado da query no código do aplicativo, eu faria uma única query simples (sem usar *table variable*) e faria um loop de 0 a 7 no aplicativo, atribuindo Zero como total para os status inexistentes na tabela `Ordem`.

Comment: É possível fazer um loop no Ireport e inserir os valores zero para os status que não foram retornados? No caso estou plotando um gráfico de pizza e uma tabela

Comment: @PedroA. Não conheço o Ireport então não sei :-) De qualquer modo esta solução que eu dei serve pra tua necessidade. Execute isso tudo como um simples select e você terá o resultado que precisa.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma solução bem interessante e genérica para esses casos, onde você deseja exibir valores que não existem no banco de dados. Valores onde os JOINS não resolvem, já que não existem os registros no banco de dados.

Essa solução se baseia na utilização de uma tabela que contém somente um campo do tipo int e é preenchida com 999999 de registros.

É a famosa tabela Numbers (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable). Obviamente, o nome pouco importa, mas é chamada por muitos de Numbers.

Como criar e preencher essa tabela no SQL Server pode ser visto aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80506/3084

para utilizá-la, no seu contexto, faça assim:

```
SELECT NUMBER, COUNT(T.STATUS)
FROM NUMBERS N
LEFT JOIN TABELA T
ON (T.STATUS = N.NUMBER)
WHERE N.NUMBER <= 8
GROUP BY NUMBER
```

SQLFiddle com esse exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b80e/1/0

Entenda a Numbers como um canivete suiço. Você consegue resolver vários problemas desse tipo utilizando ela.

Um outro exemplo bem famoso é quando precisamos mostrar a produção para todos os dias do mês, inclusive para os dias onde a produção foi 0. Com a Numbers isso fica muito fácil, já que ela contém todos os dias.

Comment: obrigado pela sua resolução com ela também é possível solucionar o meu problema.

Comment: sim, a vantagem dela é que você consegue usá-la em outras situações. Você cria a tabela Numbers apenas uma vez e depois reutiliza onde precisar. É uma solução bem simples e flexível.