# SQL - Retornar registros zerados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia,

Tenho uma query que está retornando apenas os meses com consumo de vendas, o que deveria ser o correto. Só que agora uma abençoada usuária quer quer eu retorne todos os meses, inclusive os que não tiveram vendas. Como faço para retornar como zero inclusive aquilo que está sendo excluso na consulta? rs.

Segue código:

```
SELECT Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) AS EMISSAO, 
   Sum(C6_QTDVEN - C6_QTDENT)  AS PERDA 
FROM   SC5010 SC5 WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN SC6010 SC6 WITH (NOLOCK) 
               ON C6_FILIAL = '01' 
                  AND C6_NUM = C5_NUM 
                  AND C6_PRODUTO = '6020210'
                  AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    LEFT JOIN SD2010 SD2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
              ON D2_FILIAL = '01' 
                 AND D2_PEDIDO = C5_NUM 
                 AND D2_COD = C6_PRODUTO 
                 AND D2_SERIE != 'R' 
                 AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    LEFT JOIN SF2010 SF2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
          ON F2_FILIAL = '01' 
             AND F2_DOC = C5_NOTA 
             AND F2_SERIE = C5_SERIE 
             AND SF2.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
WHERE  C5_FILIAL = '01' 
        AND Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) BETWEEN '201507' AND '201606'
        AND C5_MODAL = '2' 
        AND C5_NOTA != ' ' 
        AND SC5.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
GROUP  BY Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) 
ORDER  BY Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) DESC
```

E este é o retorno atual:

[image: Consumo]

Como podem ver, pulam-se alguns meses. Lembrando que o PERDA pode ser zerado mas nestes meses teve venda (que não aparece nesta consulta).

Preciso trazer todos os meses do intervalo contido no Where

Se alguém tiver a luz no fim do túnel, agradeço

Abraços!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução abaixo é um pequeno exemplo de como isso pode ser resolvido de uma maneira simples. Ela é baseada nessa [reposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81094/3084) e considera que exista uma tabela chamada Numbers (ou qualquer outro nome), no banco de dados. Para criar a tabela veja esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80506/3084).

O SQL (que utiliza a tabela SRA020 do Protheus como exemplo), é o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
 NUMBER ANO_MES,
 COUNT(RA_ADMISSA)
FROM 
 NUMBERS N 
 LEFT JOIN SRA020 
 ON (LEFT(RA_ADMISSA, 6) = NUMBER)
WHERE 
 NUMBER >= 201601 AND NUMBER <= 201608
GROUP BY NUMBER
```

Explicando:

A tabela Numbers é uma tabela que possui apenas um campo do tipo int (chave primária) e é populada com 999999 de registros (pode ser pouplada com mais, se necessário).

Dentro desses 999.999 registros, haverão, por exemplo os registros (numeros inteiros): 201601, 201602, 201603 (que também são datas no formado *anomes*).

Pois bem, no exemplo acima (que pode ser replicado facilmente para o SQL da pergunta), o JOIN entre a tabela do Protheus e Number é feito com um simples LEFT(RA_ADMISSA,6), que retorna os 6 primeiros dígitos do campo data (ou seja, o ano e mes). A partir daí, basta limitar o período consultado no WHERE.

Nesse pequeno exemplo, mostra-se a quantidade de admissões feitas de 01/2016 a 08/2016. Como em Jul e Ago ainda não tiveram admissões (ou registros na tabela SRA020), o sql retorna 0 para esses períodos.

Isso acontece, pois a consulta é feita em cima da NUMBERS e um LEFT JOIN é feito com a SRA020, é feito assim, pois, obviamente, todos os períodos (numeros inteiros) constam na NUMBERS, mas o contrário não é verdade.

A Numbers é um canivete suiço e, como tal, possui vários usos. Veja [aqui](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11564).

Comment: Muito interessante Cantoni. Vou dar uma olhada no link que passou e fazer alguns testes. Preciso ver se a aplicação deste conceito poderá fazer com que eu ganhe mais alguns segundos de performance. Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Opa Caio,
Cara só uma duvida é uma query normal ou esta em uma View?

Certo você pode fazer o CASE Segue um trecho de exemplo no Protheus na tabela SC6

```
    CASE WHEN C6_BLQ = ' ' THEN (SC6.C6_QTDVEN - SC6.C6_QTDENT) ELSE 0 END 'SALDO',
,(SC6.C6_QTDVEN - SC6.C6_QTDENT) WHEN 0 THEN 'FATURADO' ELSE CASE SC9.C9_BLEST WHEN '' THEN 'LIBERADO' ELSE 'BLOQUEADO' END   END  AS STATUS, 
CASE WHEN C6_BLQ = ' ' THEN (SC6.C6_QTDVEN - SC6.C6_QTDENT) ELSE 0 END 'SALDO',
CASE (SC6.C6_QTDVEN - SC6.C6_QTDENT) WHEN 0 THEN 'FATURADO' ELSE CASE SC9.C9_BLEST WHEN '' THEN 'LIBERADO' ELSE 'BLOQUEADO' END   END  AS STATUS,
```

Comment: Olá Amigo, É uma query normal. Case, hm, vou pensar em como fazer mas até o momento não tive ideias.

Comment: Caio, você também pode cria um função no SQL e chamar na sua query, mas se for chamar essa função em um código Advpl, não ira funcionar, pelo menos nunca consegui, e não vi ninguém que conseguiu.
Ex função :

Comment: Esta query eu joguei como Procedure no banco e chamo via advpl. Fiz isso pois precisava ganhar um pouco de performance, esta consulta é chamada mais de 40 x por dia em 8 estações de trabalho. Melhorou mas agora querem mexer neste retorno incluindo informações nulas. Estou pensando se é mais fácil mexer no que está pronto ou ajustar dentro do ADVPL para preencher informação além do que a query traz

Comment: Caio, é melhor fazer no SQL por causa da performance, bem como é mais simples para manutenção. Mas se ficar muito complexo ai vai no Advpl mesmo!

Comment: Acabei criando tabelas temporárias com ANO e MÊS e com o resultado da outra query.. Depois um LEFT JOIN entre as duas, retornou o que eu precisava.

Comment: Blz, Caio valeu!

Comment: E a solução ficou bem interessante!

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda de um colega, chegamos neste final:

```
    SELECT Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) AS EMISSAO, 
   Sum(C6_QTDVEN - C6_QTDENT)  AS PERDA 
   INTO #TEMP1 
FROM   SC5010 SC5 WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN SC6010 SC6 WITH (NOLOCK) 
               ON C6_FILIAL = '01' 
                  AND C6_NUM = C5_NUM 
                  AND C6_PRODUTO = @CPRODUTO
                  AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    LEFT JOIN SD2010 SD2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
              ON D2_FILIAL = '01' 
                 AND D2_PEDIDO = C5_NUM 
                 AND D2_COD = C6_PRODUTO 
                 AND D2_SERIE != 'R' 
                 AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    LEFT JOIN SF2010 SF2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
          ON F2_FILIAL = '01' 
             AND F2_DOC = C5_NOTA 
             AND F2_SERIE = C5_SERIE 
             AND SF2.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
WHERE  C5_FILIAL = '01' 
        AND Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) BETWEEN @CDATAINI AND @CDATAFIM
        AND C5_MODAL = '2' 
        AND C5_NOTA != ' ' 
        AND SC5.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
GROUP  BY Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) 
ORDER  BY Substring(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) DESC 

    --Cria temporaria com todos os meses de consulta
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) EMISSAO
    INTO #ANOMESSP
FROM SC5010 SC5
    WHERE D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    AND SUBSTRING(C5_EMISSAO, 1, 6) BETWEEN @CDATAINI AND @CDATAFIM

SELECT A.EMISSAO, ISNULL(B.PERDA, 0) PERDA 
    FROM #ANOMESSP A 
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP1 B on A.EMISSAO = B.EMISSAO
ORDER BY EMISSAO DESC
```

Obrigado JMFROLIM por toda a ajuda também!

Abraços